# Can't concatenate additional data to CNN + RNN architecture

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, lstm

I am trying to create a CNN + LSTM Network, but in addition to the CNN output the LSTM gets additional data added as input. I am trying to concatenate both the CNN output and the additional Input, but I can't get it to work.

`cnn_input = Input(shape=(256, 256, 3), name="cnn_input")
cnn_layer1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same", activation="relu")(
cnn_input
)
cnn_layer1_pooling = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2, padding="same")(cnn_layer1)

```
    cnn_layer2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same", activation="relu")(
        cnn_layer1_pooling
    )
    cnn_layer2_pooling = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2, padding="same")(cnn_layer2)

    cnn_layer3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same", activation="relu")(
        cnn_layer2_pooling
    )
    cnn_layer3_pooling = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=2, padding="same")(cnn_layer3)

    cnn_layer4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), strides=1, padding="same", activation="relu")(
        cnn_layer3_pooling
    )
    cnn_output = TimeDistributed(Flatten())(cnn_layer4)
    cnn_output_dense = Dense(700, activation="relu")(cnn_output)
    # Define the input for weather data
    weather_input = Input(shape=(4,), name="weather_input")

    # Concatenate the CNN output and weather data
    merged = Concatenate(cnn_output_dense, weather_input)

    lstm_layer1 = LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)(merged)
    lstm_layer2 = LSTM(32, return_sequences=True)(lstm_layer1)
    lstm_output = LSTM(32)(lstm_layer2)

    # Dense layer for final output
    dense_output = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(lstm_output)

    # Build the model
    model = Model(inputs=cnn_input, outputs=dense_output)
    model.compile(
        loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"]
    )
    model.summary()`
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate layer provided by TensorFlow **takes a list of tensor as an input**. You can check more details on the documentation page of the Concatenate layer and see the code example there.

Simply add square brackets inside the Concatenate(), it will result like this:

```
merged = Concatenate([cnn_output_dense, weather_input])
```

Try this and your code will run just fine.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add this, but i am trying to use that as the input of the LSTM `merged = Concatenate()([cnn_output_dense, weather_input])

    
    lstm_layer1 = LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)(merged)` I still get this error: ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concatenation axis. Received: input_shape=[(None, 2, 1200), (None, 4)]

Comment: Your `cnn_output_dense` is still 3D data, because `TimeDistributed(Flatten())(cnn_layer4)` does nothing. Why do you want to use `TimeDistributed` with `Flatten`? This cancels the flattening of the 2D data, because you project it along one axis (1D), and it is still 2D. Which can't be concatenated with the 1D `wheather_input`.